# Breaking a Lease because of construction

Tags: residential-lease

I'm renting a two bedroom apartment with a large terrace in NYC. The terrace has been rendered unusable due to maintenance on the exterior. The terrace is filled with equipment, and the door to the terrace is blocked.  The maintenance will continue until the summer. Do I have grounds to break the lease or request a rent reduction?

Comment: I doubt it, but the terms of your lease are essential for determining what rights you have in this regard.

Comment: In contrast to @IñakiViggers I think you can indeed request a rent reduction, though it does indeed depend somewhat on the terms of the lease (see for example https://www.nytimes.com/2008/05/28/realestate/28qa-001.html).  Breaking the lease is another matter, but should be possible, if perhaps difficult.  Unfortunately landlord and tenant lawyers in New York City are expensive.